# Symfony: Retrieving and displaying data from database using form submission

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want a form that when a user enters that data they want to search for that it directs to a page that will display a list from the database. For an example I have a form that will search a person by their first name.

My SearchByFirstNameType.php:

```
class SearchByFirstNameType extends AbstractType
 {
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
    $builder
        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->add('firstname','search',array(
            'label' => 'First Name:'
        ))
        ->add('submit', 'submit');
     }

   public function getName()
     {
       return 'searchbyfirstname';
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
 $searchperson = new Person();

 $searchpersonform = $this->createForm(new SearchByFirstNameType(), $searchperson);

 if($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == 'GET') {
    $searchpersonform->bind($this->getRequest());
    if($searchpersonform->isValid()) {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CIRBundle:Person');
        $person = $repository->findOneByFirstname($searchperson);
       }
    }

     return $this->render('CIRBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        'personform'        => $personform->createView(),
        'searchpersonform'  => $searchpersonform->createView(),
            'person'                => $person
    ));             
}
```

In index.html.twig template it is giving me a "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form." error. Also, 'person' is not defined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the template code please.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF is [Cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). You need CSRF-token to protect your form from being sent from another site. It can be useful if you have some valuable information that can be changed or retrieved via form submission only for authorised user. The fraudster's site can have the same form as you have (it will lead user to your site) but with specified data that can be useful for fraudster (e.g. it can be payment details where receiver=fraudster if you have payment service). In this cases you need some protection. Symfony gives you that protection by default.

But you can disable this protection if you don't need it. For example in your case you use form for simple search. If all your users have ability to search via this field there is no reason to worry.

To disable CSRF for your form add this method to your `SearchByFirstNameType`:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ));
}
```

Comment: I'll remove the `-1` if you explain to OP what CSRF is and why he can disable it in this particular context (search form). The answer as is doesn't help OP understand the problem it just gives him an easy fix and tomorrow he'll be none the wiser.

Comment: reasonable... I changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your template is rendering the form fields individually in a custom HTML such as using `form_row()` or `form_widget()` etc..

In the above case you are manually rendering the form elements that **you** created but Symfony2 forms have some extra hidden fields such as the CSRF protection field.

Because of the above reason whenever you manually render a form you should use `form_rest(form)` which renders the missing fields (all of the fields that you didn't already render manually).

Comment: CSRF protection for search field? Is it a joke? It is overhead that isn't needed to author.

Comment: This is Symfony2's default behavior even if it is not necessary in this particular case.

Comment: Disabling CSRF protection **after** understanding why this problem occurred and exactly what CSRF does and how to fix this on any type of form is a decision the author makes after informing himself.